# Codeigniter views: How can I create subdirectories for my views?

Tags: php, codeigniter, directory-structure, templating

In my views folder for codeigniter I would like to have a sub directory for each of my categories.

- /home
- /about us
- /services

and each of these will contain different views.

How can I point the controller to the views in these directories and how can I make the default route for / reference a sub directory???

Answer (score 7):

`$this->load->view('path/to/view/file')` will load the relevant view if it's nested in a sub directory.

As for the default route, just make your default controller load the correct (or default view) using the code above

Comment: Please help check my problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39360697/link-to-view-inside-subfolder-does-not-display-correctly